# How to call my code (a dll file) by using add-ons and js-ctypes on Firefox (Windows)

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jsctypes

I ran the code, but encountered the following error:

```
1423705078419   Services.HealthReport.HealthReporter    WARN    Saved state file does not exist.
1423705078420   Services.HealthReport.HealthReporter    WARN    No prefs data found.
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

My code:

```
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
var {ctypes} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm", null);
lib = ctypes.open("C:\\gmc\\posinf.dll");
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out? :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code from firefox-addon-sdk? Or from bootstrap addon? If from bootstrap then there is no `require` function defined.

```
var {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');
var lib = ctypes.open('C:\\gmc\\posinf.dll');
```